# Search in a List that starts with a string in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a list of string and I need to check whether the given string matches or starts with any of the string in the list.
For example:

Match(e: Employees)
With e.Code as empCode
Where e.Code STARTS WITH ['CLR', 'MVV', 'OPP']
Return *

Here the e.Code can be CLR1, MVV2, OPP1, OPP, CLR, CLR2, MVV1, SVV1
So I want to return e that has code  CLR1, MVV2, OPP1, OPP, CLR, CLR2, MVV1, SVV1
But I will only have this list: ['CLR', 'MVV', 'OPP'].

I tried using foreach, but I cannot use WHERE inside foreach. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ANY` predicate:

```
MATCH (e:Employees) 
WHERE ANY(x IN ['CLR', 'MVV', 'OPP'] WHERE e.Code STARTS WITH x)
RETURN *
```